# Show that it exists $M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $m(\{|f|>M\})<ε $

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ be a measurable function and almost everywhere finite function $f:[a,b]\to [-\infty,+\infty]$, show that for every $ε>0$ it exists a real number $M$  such that $m(\{|f|>M\})<ε $

---

"*for every $ε>0$ it exists a real number $M$  such that ..." it reminds the definition of a continuous function, I don't know if I can use this somehow.*

My approach was to say that:

Let $A$ be the set that $f$ is **not** finite, by hypothesis $m(A)=0$

$f^{-1}[-\infty,+\infty]=[a,b]$ thus it must exist a set $B$ s.t $f^{-1}(B)=A$

if $B$ contains an interval, then it exists $M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(-M,+M)=A' \subset A
\Rightarrow \{|f|>M\}=A' \Rightarrow m(\{|f|>M\})=0$

**I am not sure if I can show that $B$ contains an interval, any hints ?**

Comment: You say $A'$ is two different (disjoint) sets

Comment: Hint: $A=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty|[|f|>n\}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Could you explain a little more why $A= \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty }\left \{ \left | f \right |>n \right \} $  ? (if that is what you wrote), then by taking $M=n$ we done correct ?

Comment: I think you are using the wrong inequality in the last line of your argument. Notice that $f^{- \, 1}(- \, M, + M) = \{f \in (- \, M, + M) \} = \{ | f | < M \}$ and not the other way around. A nice proof of this statement follows the lines of @DavidC.Ullrich comment, using a property called monotone continuity from above

Comment: $|f(x)|=\infty$ if and only if $|f(x)|>n$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: @GiordanoRibeiro oh I totally missed that.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David C. Ullrich commented, a nice way of proving this proposition is doing the following:

First, since $f$ is measurable, it is also the case that $|f|$ is measurable (since we are talking about an extended real valued function, measurability means $(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{\overline{R}}))$ - measurability, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the $\sigma$ - algebra of our measure space). Now, we can create the following sequence of sets

\begin{equation*}
\forall \, n \in \mathbb{N}, \; B_n = \{ |f| > n \}.
\end{equation*}

Since $|f|$ is measurable, $B_n \in \mathcal{F}$ and $B_{n + 1} \subseteq B_n$, for all $n$. Further, $m(B_1) = m(\{ |f| > 1 \}) \leq m([a, b]) = b - a < \infty$, $\textit{i.e.}$, our sequence of sets has finite measure. These are all the ingredients we need to use monotone continuity from above and, consequently, we have that

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} m(B_n) = m\left(\bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty B_n \right).
\end{equation*}

As David pointed out in the comments, it is clear that $\{ |f| = \infty \} = \cap_{n = 1}^\infty B_n$, which means that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} m(B_n) = 0 \; (*)$. After this (really) long preamble we can finally prove the theorem.

Consider an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $(*)$, we can use the epsilon in the definition of limit to get that

\begin{equation*}
\exists \, n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \, \text{s.t.} \, \forall \, n > n_0, \, | \mu(B_n) - 0| < \varepsilon.
\end{equation*}

Simply define $M = n_0 + 1$. Then

\begin{equation*}
m(\{ |f| > M \}) = m(\{ |f| > n_0 + 1 \}) = m(B_{n_0 + 1}) = |m(B_{n_0 + 1}) - 0| < \varepsilon.
\end{equation*}

which completes the proof. Hope it help!

Comment: It helped a lot, thank you for the explicit answer, I am glad I did manage to prove it correctly after the hint.